# sed command and grouping

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file called test and it contains:

```
EMS_INSTANCES_DIR=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async
EMS_SHARED_CONFIG=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async/shared/config
EMS_SHARED_DATA=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async/shared/data
EMS_JMS_PORT=15244
EMS_INTERFACE=tcp://adecpcas:15244
EMS_KEYS=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/keys
```

and I want to change the path after = to /test/path

I use `sed` to do that:

```
sed 's/\(^EMS_[SIJ].*\=\)\(\/.*[a-z]$\)/\1\/test/path/' test
```

but no changes happened, why?.

Comment: Ack, the toothpicks are leaning!  You don't have to use `/` as the delimiter; please don't if your strings contain slashes, to avoid all the extra backslashes.  If you use `-E` you can also remove the backslashes on the grouping parentheses: `sed -E 's,^(EMS_[SIJ][^=]*=).*$,\1/test/path,` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's:=/.*:=/test/path:' file
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "EMS_INSTANCES_DIR=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async
EMS_SHARED_CONFIG=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async/shared/config
EMS_SHARED_DATA=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async/shared/data
EMS_JMS_PORT=15244
EMS_INTERFACE=tcp://adecpcas:15244"|sed 's:=/.*:=/test/path:'
EMS_INSTANCES_DIR=/test/path
EMS_SHARED_CONFIG=/test/path
EMS_SHARED_DATA=/test/path
EMS_JMS_PORT=15244
EMS_INTERFACE=tcp://adecpcas:15244
```

if you want to change in place, add `-i`

**EDIT** for the comment:

```
sed 's@\(^EMS_[SIJ].*=/\).*@\1test/path/@' file
```

with same example:

```
kent$  echo "EMS_INSTANCES_DIR=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async
EMS_SHARED_CONFIG=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async/shared/config
EMS_SHARED_DATA=/WEB_DATA/home/edofc24/EMS-INSTANCES/async/shared/data
EMS_JMS_PORT=15244
EMS_INTERFACE=tcp://adecpcas:15244"|sed 's@\(^EMS_[SIJ].*=/\).*@\1test/path/@'
EMS_INSTANCES_DIR=/test/path/
EMS_SHARED_CONFIG=/test/path/
EMS_SHARED_DATA=/test/path/
EMS_JMS_PORT=15244
EMS_INTERFACE=tcp://adecpcas:15244
```

Comment: but sorry the file contains some lines also that have /paths also

Comment: @M_E, next time please clarify it in your question, you just wrote "it contains:"

Comment: @M_E see Edit, if it is ok 4 u.

Comment: It is working fine, but I want to understand
sed 's@\(^EMS_[SIJ].*=/\).*@\1test/path/@' what's =/ why / is used? and why you didn't grouped the rest of line

Comment: @M_E the beginning I think I don't have to explain, just copied your code. `=/` in group1, because, I assume if the next char after `=` is slash, the value would be a path. at least from your example, it is so. the rest we don't have to group them. because, only `\1` is important for us, the value we have fixed string : `/test/path/` In your codes, in fact, you grouped the 2nd group, but you didn't reference it in your replacement part either. I hope you got it clear by now.